# Loop over the execution of SQL Scripts in Maven

Tags: sql, maven, ant, pom.xml, mojo

basically in the pom of my maven project I'm trying to iterate through some folders and execute SQL scripts that are contained in these folders. The names of the folders follow a sequence, so I was thinking about using a loop sentence with ant, however I don't know how to mix that with the execution of sql scripts made with mojo plugin.

The structure of my directory is as follows, the scripts I want to execute are inside 'db_scripts' folders:

[image: Maven project directory]

I'll appreciate any sincere help.

Comment: You might want to look into tools like Liquibase and Flyway - they can handle all that for you. And both have a Maven plugin

Comment: Could you not post an image but a text representation of it instead?

Answer (score 0):

- You have 2 solutions :

  1. use executions :

Example

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version> 
             <executions>
              <execution>
                 <id>default-@your_goal@</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>your_goal</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  ...
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>id2</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>@your_goal@</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  ...
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>  
          </plugin>
```

2. Iterator-maven-plugin

http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/